# automatically currency rate conversion in laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `Product` model included `sale_price` , `purchase_price`.this fields holds values as **IRR (Iranian rial)** currency, means that when an operator user is saving a product ,specifies Sale and Purchase prices in IRR currency in default.

Now in many situations I want to show a list of all products along with their  prices that default is same currency that I stored in DB.

Then I want User can switch to another currency(for example via a combo box) and page refreshed and same list of products shown with new selected currency .

I have checked some currency exchange rate packages like [laravel-swap](https://github.com/florianv/laravel-swap) and [laravel-currency](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency) but I did not find any capability to do what I want.

Seems that one approach is define an **accessor** for each financial fields that uses methods of one of the mentioned packages. but it's Time-consuming if there are many fields.

On the Other hand when a user uses a currency Opposite of Default then we must to define a **mutator** to convert it and save in DB.

I am confused which approach should be used and what is best and common way.

Comment: I think you should be able to define load the mutatorr once and then use it for all products. Don't know exactly why you want to save it in db.

Comment: Without code it's hard to help... :-)

Comment: @dieter-pollier , it's simple. I want just prices with default currency (IRR) even if user is on dollar US currency status.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is automatic, You'll have to do it yourself.

Make a table & put the exchange rates in there

```
exchange_rates
------------
currency_code        exchange_rate      Default
IRR                  1                  Yes
USD                  0.000028           No
```

Then it's just a matter of multiplication when displaying the prices, You can make your own helper functions to do that or a formatter or whatever.
You can then either change the exchange rates manually once per day or use an API to pull-in the exchange rate & create something like an artisan console command to do the job.